# how to remove user name and date in post page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

Every post page shows user name and date in top of page.
Pinboard theme is used.
Wordpress is used like CMS and this info in not nessecary. Pages cannto used since pages does not allow to add tags and cannot used as slider images in pinboard.

How to remove user and date ?

There are also categories and Edit buttons. If this is simpler, they can removed also so that whole line can removed.
If possible, categories link may remain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to use Pinboard theme as parent theme and make your small changes by modifying specific templates such as `page.php`, `single.php`, etc.

This would allow you to modify Pinboard theme without hard coding it and if the theme is updated you can update without losing your modifications.